# Is there a recommended electronic board (similar to this) where Product Designers / Industrial Designers can be found?

Tags: discussion

Ie people whose background is designing physical 'stuff' rather than software ?

Comment: If you have an off topic question like this, it's better to ask in chat.

Comment: Sorry. I'd assumed the Meta board was to talk about the UX board.

Comment: Within the Stack Exchange universe, this ought to be the place where those people hang out. If you have questions about designing physical "stuff," please ask here and use the [tag:physical] tag.

Comment: @PhillipW Yeah, I don't think it was such an inappropriate question for the main site. But it was closed by the time I saw it, and figured no one would object to having it open here.

Comment: It seems to show up on the main list on UX - so I guess it'll get noticed anyhow.  I've added a physical tag.

Comment: You can ask about physical stuff too, physical items have a user experience all the same, though less people on this site are likely to have direct knowledge about it, but many concepts remain the same if you're talking about the usability and experience of the objects (Design of Everyday Things anyone?) not just "how do I make X physical object and with what tools?"

Comment: As someone well observed on Amazon 'The Psychology of Everyday Things' (its original title) is about how the human brain interacts with the world.  User Experience is a common process wherever human brains interact with the world.  http://www.amazon.co.uk/product-reviews/0262640376/ref=cm_cr_dp_hist_5?ie=UTF8&showViewpoints=0&filterBy=addFiveStar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core77 is the main web hangout for IDers: boards.core77.com

Comment: That's a great board. Quite a few topics from here are also on there...